# /etc/fstab is mounting rw filesystem as read-only

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, automounting, fstab

A partition of my internal hard drive (not the root partition) I want to mount automatically on boot. I've been using /etc/fstab to mount my external backup drive automatically read-only, so this is the first drive I've tried to mount read-write with fstab. Here's the relevant line:

```
/dev/sda3   /media/^_^    vfat    rw,sync,user    0   0
```

Yes, my drive is a silly face. The `^` hasn't caused me any problems before, but maybe it's interfering with something here? Though I doubt it — the drive mounts fine except that it is read-only.

Any reason why this would happen? I've tried restarting multiple times.

Comment: What's the output of `mount -l`? Have you tried testing using the options `auto,user,uid=your_uid_here,umask=077,rw`?

Comment: Ah it seems that for some strange reason, it's defaulting to noexec. I'll try restarting with exec explicitly mentioned.

Comment: The option `user` automatically implies `noexec, nosuid, nodev` unless overridden. This seems not to be the problem though. A tip: to easily remount with new options: `mount -o remount,rw /dev/foo /dir`

Comment: Adding exec didn't fix the read-only problem. Would nosuid or nodev interfere with that? It doesn't seem so.

Comment: Is there anything in `dmesg` about the partition? You might also want to look at `fdisk -l /dev/sda3` to see if that reveals anything.

Comment: What is your filesystem? Do you get any warnings or other messages when you manually remount it (e.g. by `mount -a`)? Note that mounting an inconsistent FAT fs mounts it read-only (see [mount manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)).

Comment: @delwin Have you tried mounting it on `/mnt/^_^` instead of `/media/^_^`?

Comment: @Adam Zalcman: It is vfat. I get no warnings (unless I do it as non-root user). How do I know if it's "inconsistent?"

Comment: By looking into the output of `dmesg` and seeing if there's any message from the vfat driver saying the partition has issues and will be mounted read-only. You can also run `fsck`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use UUID instead of using device name. Because the name of this device (/dev/sda3) depends on the order in which it was detected while booting, and this order can change. Type this command "blkid" without quote, the shell will display all the devices with UUID. Refer below:

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ blkid
/dev/sda2: UUID="2fc45c8c-7420-48af-8ad5-06cfeda8633b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="9a070d16-c6be-40a2-8f38-2e52b8010ef2" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="212c65ba-f4bf-4840-8bcc-bb83c5fe63e6" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="USBtest" UUID="5f42b5d0-375d-4802-8c58-bd6c9c62481b" TYPE="ext4" 
[admin@localhost ~]$
```

Above is an example. Copy your device UUID, then replace with /dev/sda3. Then reboot your server. Hope this can solve your problem. Thank you.